# Symfony 4 : Forms not showing input fields when using CollectionType

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm having problem with displaying form when using CollectionType. It doesn't show ClientType inputs, just label "name".

Whats wrong? I don't understand..

[image]

### SubscriptionType :

```
class SubscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

         ->add('name', CollectionType::class, array(
             'entry_type' => ClientType::class,
             'allow_add' => true,
             'prototype' => true,
         ))

            ->add('enabled', null, array(
                'label'    => 'Activer le contrat de support'), [
                'required'   => false,
            ])
            ->add('startDate', DateTimePickerType::class, [
                'label' => 'Date de début de la formation',
                'help' => 'La formation peut être programmée en sélectionnant une date future',
            ])
            ->add('endDate', DateTimePickerType::class, [
                'label' => 'Date de fin de la formation',
                'help' => 'Sélectionnez la date de fin de la formation',
            ]);
    }


    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Subscription::class,
            'name' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

### ClientType :

```
class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder

        ->add('name', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Clients::class,
            'label'    => 'Domaine du client',
        ])

        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Clients::class,
            'name' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

**And in my Twig template I have :**

```
{% block body %}

    <h1>{{ 'Ajout d\'un client' }}</h1>

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    <ul id="name-fields-list"
        data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.name.vars.prototype)|e }}"
        data-widget-tags="{{ '<li></li>'|e }}"
        data-widget-counter="{{ form.children|length }}">
        {% for nameField in form.name %}
            <li>
                {{ form_errors(nameField) }}
                {{ form_widget(nameField) }}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <button type="button"
            class="add-another-collection-widget"
            data-list-selector="#email-fields-list">Add another customer</button>

    {{ form_row(form.enabled) }}
    {{ form_row(form.startDate) }}
    {{ form_row(form.endDate) }}

    <script src="{{ asset('build/js/add-collection-widget.js') }}"></script>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-save" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'Ajout d\'un client' }}
    </button>
    <a href="{{ path('support_admin_client_index') }}" class="btn btn-link">
        <i class="fa fa-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{ 'Retour à la liste des clients' }}
    </a>
    {{ form_end(form) }}


{% endblock %}


{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/js/add-collection-widget.js')  }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

I have activate the "prototype" option because I have an "allow_add" and in my twig I have `data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.name.vars.prototype)|e }}"`

How to make it show all input fields?

Comment: do you have any data in the collection? what happens when you press 'add customer' ?

Comment: Yes, I have some data. Nothing happens when I press "add another customer" and if I press "Ajout d'un client"  i get `Expected value of type "App\Entity\Clients" for association field "App\Entity\Subscription#$name", got "array" instead.`

Comment: the error message says that your `Subscription` entity field `name` is not a collection but reference to single object, you cannot map CollectionType on single value

Comment: I just fixed this problem but the field still does not appear

Comment: `form_row(form.name)` is usually sufficient for `CollectionType`

Comment: Possibly an error in your javascript function. Can you post your `build/js/add-collection-widget.js` script? That seems to be what is not working.

Comment: also, if your javascript `{% block javascript %}` is included somewhere, it will have been added twice (the same file is included in the body block as well). Overall it might very well be, that your javascript is flawed. The prototype attribute is usually added by symfony when you `form_widget` a collection with `allow_add`, and you wouldn't have to add it yourself...